# Parametric transitive closure of an undirected graph in networkX

Tags: python, networkx, graph-theory

I am making an undirected graph from existing edges.

```
G = nx.Graph()
edge_list = [(1,2),(2,3), (3,4), (4,5),(5,6)]
G.add_edges_from(edge_list)
```

Now I want to perform transitive closure that is parametrized by level `k` such that `k=1` means following new edges will be added.

```
new_edge_list = [(1,3),(2,4),(3,5),(4,6)]
G.add_edges_from(new_edge_list)
```

While `k=2` means following new edges would be added.

```
new_edge_list = [(1,3),(1,4),(2,4),(2,5),(3,5), (3,6),(4,6)]
G.add_edges_from(new_edge_list)
```

This essentially means that as we keep on increasing the value of `k`, the graph `G` would eventually become a clique (i.e. a transitive closure). However, I want to get a transitive closure at a specific level of `k`. I am able to get full transitive closure using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48416445/creating-cliques-from-connected-components-using-networkx). But I am struggling with specific level of transitive closure. I am able to achieve `k=1` transitive closure by using [adjacency](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/generated/networkx.convert.to_dict_of_lists.html#networkx.convert.to_dict_of_lists) representation but that cannot be scaled for `k=2`.

P.S: It is okay if symmetric edges are also created like `[(1,3),(3,1)]` during parametric transitive closure.

Comment: What scaling issues do you encounter? (If you have a working algorithm for the `k = 1`-case, couldn't you just repeat that; use the output of the `k = 1`-closure as the input to the same algorithm whose output would then be the `k = 2`-closure?)

Comment: OMG! Yes.... I would be getting the desired result by recursive calls. Sleep deprivation affects basic thinking I believe!!! Thank you!

Comment: Great. Allow me to just add that as an answer then, so as to avoid having the question marked as open still.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a working algorithm for the `k = 1` case, and that the scaling issues you mention do not appear as a result of the graph itself growing as you add more edges, then you can simply use that algorithm recursively, as the result of applying it to the output of the `k = 1`-case will be your `k = 2`-case.

Comment: Yes recursive call to result of `k=1` produces results for `k=2` and so on. Thanks again!